# Max height for items in LazyVerticalGrid with even space

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I want to vertically arrange items evenly in a LazyVerticalGrid.
The grid has a fixed column size.
My goal is to space them evenly and that the items use the maximum height of that space.
Is that achievable in a LazyVerticalGrid?
This pictures show how it currently is:

[image]

With the code being the following:

```
Column (
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
) {
   ...
    val weekDays: List<String> = listOf("M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S", "S")


    LazyVerticalGrid(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(7),
        //verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ) {
        items(weekDays) {weekDay ->
            Text(text = "$weekDay", fontSize = 20.sp)
        }
        items(offsetDays.value) {_ ->
            TextButton(
                onClick = { "" },
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp),
                border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Gray),
                modifier = Modifier.weight(2f).height(IntrinsicSize.Max)
            ) {
                Text(text = "", fontSize = 20.sp )
            }

        }
        items((calendar.value.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))) { day ->
            TextButton(
                onClick = { "" },
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp),
                border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Gray),
                modifier = Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Max)
            ) {
                Text(text = "${day + 1}", fontSize = 20.sp )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I uncomment the verticalArrangement in the LazyVerticalGrid it looks like the following:

[image]

This is almost as I would like to have but with the textButton filling the entire height of their space.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what you are trying?

Comment: @Abhimanyu I added further information :)